# How to perform mass-balance analysis with ArcHydro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arc-hydro, waterways

I was wondering if there is any online manual/instruction for carrying out water mass balance analysis using ArcHydro?

I have searched for such information, and the closest thing I can find is a course outline [from ESRI](http://www.esri.de/~/media/esri.../arc-hydro-gis-for-water-resources.pdf), which contains a section under `Arc Hydro in action` called

```
Mass-balance analysis; watershed delineation and characterization
```

But the course material itself is not available.

I was wondering if someone know how to do water mass-balance analysis with ArcHydro?

For disclosure, I know the very basics such as DEM editing, sinks filling, flow direction and accumulation; and I know some ArcGIS network analysis programming through ArcObjects/COM. What I am interested in knowing is the following

I have shapefiles for river center lines, and DEMs, administrative boundaries.

I also have monthly water level data for SOME gauge stations (but not for all segments of the river).

I want to figure out the amount of water that flows into and out of specific regions and administrative areas such as provinces.

Can I do this with ArcHydro? and How?

Comment: I might be mistaken but I don't think you can do it using ArcHydro. I have developed two tools in the open-source GIS Whitebox GAT that take flow direction, loading, efficiency, and absorption rasters as inputs and performs a simple mass balance. I know of a couple of professors who use these tools for teaching and I assumed it was because it wasn't available in ArcGIS. Again, I could be wrong and perhaps someone here can tell me so.

Comment: @WhiteboxDev Thanks a lot for the info. Could you provide some pointers to the mass balance functions in Whitebox GAT you mentioned?

Comment: Here is a link to the help docs on the D-infinity version of Whitebox's mass balance tool (there is also a D8 version):  http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/Help/MassFluxDinf.html  It is a rather basic approach and is not a substitute for a dynamic hydrological model if that is more what you are looking for. Nonetheless it will allow you to perform loading/absorption based flow accumulation for an area.

Comment: ArcHydro can't handle flow volumes or water levels. For that you either need @WhiteboxDev's tools or some specialized application like Hec-ras or Mike 11/She/21/Flood (several different programs in the same group).

Comment: @TingL I agree with Martin; depending on your application, you might be best off using a full-blown hydrological model.